# What's required to build a complete HTTP reverse proxy in go?

Tags: go, reverse-proxy

A naive reverse proxy is like this:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
    "fmt"
)

func main() { 
    // New functionality written in Go
    http.HandleFunc("/new", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "New function")
    })

    // Anything we don't do in Go, we pass to the old platform
    u, _ := url.Parse("http://www.google.com/")
    http.Handle("/", httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(u))

    // Start the server
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

But, this is incomplete.  Depending on the website you might not get anything useful back.  Some do https redirect.  Some complain about direct ip access.  I suspect virtual hosts don't work?  not sure.

What does a true reverse proxy do that makes it complete?

Comment: What's tricky is that the behaviors you want an RP to have for mirroring Google (like set the Host header and follow redirects in your example) may not be what you want from an RP made to sit in front of your app servers (in order to cache, serve static content, filter DoS attacks, or whatever). It might be hard to intuit what you'll need 'til we know what goes wrong for your app.

Comment: Check this project probably could give you some ideas https://slashquery.com

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to implement a reverse HTTP proxy in Go is with the [httputil.ReverseProxy](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy) type in the standard library.

This gives you the flexibility to set a `Director` function which can modify the incoming requests, and a `Transport` to possibly modify requests and/or responses on-the-fly.

It should be able to handle the vast majority of reverse proxy situations.  I use it with great success in a project of mine.